# Is there a way to disable Paw notifications?

Tags: notifications, paw-app

Just as the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to disable notifications. After a couple hours of development, my notification center is filled with Paw notifications. I have no use for these, as I'm generally looking at the responses anyway.

If there is currently no way to do this, I would appreciate it if you could consider adding this option to the Preferences.